# Pandas groupby slicing, but in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, group-by

I have a dataframe with float dtypes only, and an id column. I want to restrict the dataframe to just the top 10 rows for each id value. The immediate way to do that is just `df.groupby('id').apply(lambda minidf: minidf.iloc[:k])`, but it seems a bit slow and I'm wondering if there are much faster ways of getting the same output.

So I wanted to ask, since the dataframe is made up of all floats anyway, is there a numpy method I can use that's equivalent to the above line of code? Or maybe if I can achieve the same result in any other library, but in a much shorter time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Performance ideas: 1) `minidf.iloc[:k]` is equivalent to `df.groupby('id').head(k)`, not sure which is faster. 2) You can turn off group sorting by doing `df.groupby('id', sort=False)`, which makes it faster. 3) You could reduce the amount of data going into the groupby by randomly dropping 90% of the original dataframe. `df.sample(frac=0.1).groupby('id').head(k)` But this only works if you don't care which 10 rows Pandas selects, and if dropping 90% of data doesn't reduce any group below 10 rows.

Comment: Creating pandas dataframes is generally pretty slow and most Pandas operation generate a new one (which is inherently inefficient). Numpy does not have any group-by function so you need to implement that yourself typically using a sort. This is quite cumbersome and not very efficient either if there are a lot of same ID values in the dataframe. What is the type of the ID column? If this is integers, what kind of IDs are they : are they small?

Comment: @JérômeRichard although numpy does not export a generic `groupby`, some of the ufuncs contain the `reduceat` method which works in a similar manner as `groupby+action` eg to find minimum at each group, you use `np.minimum.reduceat` etc. For this particular problem, sure there is no numpy equivalent. But if you were to do groupby + min,max,sum, and a few others, numpy does contain the necessary tools

Comment: @Onyambu Yes but this assume the integers are small, otherwise this can be much slower than a sort, or a hash-map (i.e. what Pandas uses internally). Not to mention the possibly huge memory overhead. Hence my question about this IDs. Besides, ufunc also often have a significant overhead (though the whole operation can be faster than Pandas one in the end). For such a thing, if performance is critical, I prefer to implement this myself (and get a huge speed-up).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: So I'm doing this top k row splitting several times. If it's convenient to have small integers as ids, I could always create a dictionary mapping the ids (default ids are very large integers) to dummy ids that are small. Any fast solution that can work with small integer ids?

Comment: If the IDs are small, you can replace the dict (hash map) with an array in my solution. It will be faster. However, unless you already have the dict precomputed, building it (in CPython) is slow and actually slower than doing the actual computation in Numba. Using the dict directly in CPython would certainly also be slower. So in the end, it is not very interesting (unless the dict is typed using Numba types so it can be used to speed up a bit the Numba computation).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty fast solution using Numba:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

@nb.njit('bool_[:](int64[:],)')
def compute_mask(ids, max_per_group):
    unique_ids = {}
    res = np.empty(ids.size, dtype=np.bool_)
    for i in range(ids.size):
        item = ids[i]
        found = unique_ids.get(item)
        if found is None:
            unique_ids[item] = 1
            res[i] = True
        elif found < max_per_group:
            unique_ids[item] = found + 1
            res[i] = True
        else:
            res[i] = False  # Found too many times
    return res

# df = ...

mask = compute_mask(df['id'].to_numpy())

# Use `mask` here to filter the dataframe either using Numpy or Pandas.
# Creating a new dataframe in Pandas is certainly slower, but simpler.
# It can be done using Pandas with df[mask]. 
# It can be done using Numpy with df['values'].to_numpy()[mask]
```

The idea is to use a simple hash map so to count the number of repeated items and build a mask efficiently. Loops are fast in Numba and hash-map accesses are also faster than in CPython. This solution is efficient when IDs are often repeated several times. If all IDs tends to be different a (parallel) sort-based solution can be faster. Note that you may need to use the signature `bool_[:](int32[:],)`for the Numba function based on your actual dataframe ID column type.